# Push sharp - APNS Notifications not being sent

Tags: c#, cordova, notifications, push, pushsharp

I'm currently developing an app with Telerik, and I need push notifications, I have set this up using Push Sharp in my api, gcm notifications are sending correctly to android phones, but when I run sendToiOS, iPhones do not receive APNS notifications.
I have checked using break points and can see that OnNotificationSucceeded is being called, and OnNotificationFailed is not. Which would be a good sign, however the Notifications don't seem to be coming through, I think I may have something wrong with the configuration of the APNSServiceBroker. Please note that "AppleCert" is a byte array containing the .p12 certificate for the app.

```
    private static void sendToiOS(string deviceRegId,  object notificationToSend, FERIS.Data.Model.Notification notification)
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(notificationToSend);
        Apns.QueueNotification(new ApnsNotification
        {
            DeviceToken = deviceRegId,
            Payload = JObject.Parse(json)
        });
    }


    var config = new ApnsConfiguration(ApnsConfiguration.ApnsServerEnvironment.Production,AppleCert,"IFB_4222");
            Apns = new ApnsServiceBroker(config);
            Apns.OnNotificationFailed += (NotificationFailed, aggregateEx) => {
                    aggregateEx.Handle(ex => {

                    return true;
                });
            };
            Apns.OnNotificationSucceeded += (NotificationSent) => {
                Console.WriteLine("Notification Sent!");
                sentTotal++;
            };
```

Comment: Have you found any solution?